# Reading data from a txt file in Java, using a specific character to be the end point of each iteration

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I want to read data from a .txt file, which contains information to initialize an object of a class named Supplier. The file will have the following format, every line looks like this:

Company Name Phone

Product price quantity

Product price quantity

....

Product price quantity

Company Name Phone

Product price quantity

Product price quantity

....

Product price quantity

Company Name Phone
etc, etc.

In the following format, one Company would have more products than other - there is no pattern, just many companies with different products.

The data is going to be used in this way:

1. Read first line (Company Name Phone) and initialize an object Supplier.
2. Read every line untill a new (Company Name Phone) has been detected OR a specific character (like , ; or something), and initialize an object of type Product (with Productname and price) for every line and add it into the newly created Supplier object Map container via `<Product, quantity>`.
3. So in the end the Supplier object will have a Map `<Product, quantity>` of every `Product price quantity` line detected and then a new Supplier will be initialized, following the same logic.

I made the method to read from 1 line at a time and add all the information, but it's hardcoded and doesn't work for a different number of `<Product price quantity>` sequences. :(

This is my code, but as I said, it only read from a single line at a time and I can't add more than 1 `<Product, quantity>` pairs with it.

```
Orders(String suppliersFileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(suppliersFileName)); 
    String line;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] vars = line.split(" ");
        suppliers.addElement(new Supplier(vars[0], vars[1], vars[2], vars[3], Double.parseDouble(vars[4]), Integer.parseInt(vars[5])));
    }
    in.close();
}
```

I will appreciate any help, as I don't know much about BufferedReaders. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of knowing when you have reached the end of a supplier could be by having a unique character or string that you check at the beginning of your loop, and if it is equal you add the supplier. Also you could just have the number of products with the phone #.

```
String endOfSupplier = "!"; // this can be any thing
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
    if (line.equals(endOfSupplier)){ // end of supplier
        suppliers.add(supplier); // add supplier to suppliers
        supplier = null; // set to null to show that we are done with it
    }
    if (supplier == null){ // make new supplier when it's null
        supplier = new Supplier(line); // parse phone # to supplier
    }
    else {
        supplier.addProduct(line); // make method that turns string into product and add it to supplier
    }
}
```

I made the supplier equal to `null` when I added it to the list so I could tell whether I was reading a phone # or a product because when it was equal to `null` i assumed that it was a phone #.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but how will I make an object `Supplier` in the first if-block and then have it visible in the others to manipulate it aka add products to it? I have no idea how to do this. :/

Comment: @Calihog I would just make a `Supplier` instance before the loop. This way you can modify it any where inside the loop.